# Unable to open Synaptic manager, unable to install packages, what can I do?

Tags: package-management, apt, ubuntu-9.04, synaptic-pkg-mgr

I have installed the *sun java6-jdk* package but it's not installed completely.  After that it's giving an error when I try to install a new package.

In terminal when I write *"sudo apt-get install [any package name]"* I get an error like this:

```
E: could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock -open (11 Resource temporable )
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg).
```

Also Synaptic package manager is not opening and none of the packages are downloading 
through any of the methods I know.

Please help!

Comment: the lock error indicates another package manager process is already open (it could be *apt-get* or *aptitude* or *Synaptic* or something else), or it could mean the process crashed.  can't remember the fix right this second tho.

Comment: @quack - With you and random on steroids lately, I will start requesting for "someone is already editing" notifications, to not have my editing overridden the next 4 seconds :-]

Comment: do a ps -as to see what's running if it is running kill it?

Comment: @gnoupi: whoops, sorry!  there are notifications ("someone has saved this while you were editing") but i didn't get one this time.  don't worry; the new-mod-adrenaline should wear off soon.  :)